# HttpURLConnection does not free resources

Tags: java, android, httpconnection

I have the following code (Android 4):

```
private HttpURLConnection conn = null;

private synchronized String downloadUrl(String myurl) {
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader _bufferReader = null;
    try {
        URL url_service = new URL(.....);
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        System.setProperty("http.maxConnections", "5");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url_service.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(DataHandler.TIME_OUT);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(DataHandler.TIME_OUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.connect();
        StringBuilder total = null;
        if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            _bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = _bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }

        } else {
            onDomainError();
        }

        return total.toString();

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
        onDomainError();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        onDomainError();

    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }

        }
        if (_bufferReader != null) {
            try {
                _bufferReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

        if (conn != null)
            conn.disconnect();
        conn = null;

    }
    return null;
}
```

`.disconnect()` is used, keep-alive is set to false and max connections is set to 5. However, if `SocketTimeout` `exception` occurs, connections are not closed and device soon gets out-of memory. How is this possible?

Also, according to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html, `HttpURLConnection` should close connections on `disconnect()` if keep-alive is set to `false` and reuse it when keep-alive is `true`. Neither of these approaches work for me. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you are not setting the properties soon enough.  According to the javadoc, the "keepalive" property needs to be set to false *before* issuing any HTTP requests.  And that might *actually* mean before the URL protocol drivers are initialized.

Another possibility is that your OOME is not caused by this at all.  It could be caused by what your app does  with the content it has downloaded.

---

There some other problems with your code too.

- The variable names `url_service`, `_bufferedReader` and `myurl` are all violations of Java's identifier naming conventions.
- The `conn` variable should be a local variable.  Making it a field makes the `downloadUrl` method non-reentrant.  (And that *might* be contributing to your problems ... if multiple threads are sharing one instance of this object!)
- You don't need to close the buffered reader and the input stream.  Just close the reader, and it will close the stream.  This probably doesn't matter for a reader, but if you do that for a buffered writer AND you close the output stream first, you are liable to get exceptions.

---

**UPDATE**

So we definitely have lots of non-garbage `HttpURLConnectionImpl` instances, and we probably have multiple threads running this code via `AsyncTask`.

If you try to connect to a non-responding site (e.g. one where the TCP/IP connect requests are black-holing ...) then the `conn.connect()` call is going to block for a long time and eventually throw an exception.  If the connect timeout is long enough, and your code is doing a potentially unbounded number of these calls in parallel, then you are liable to have lots of these instances.

If this theory is correct, then your problem is nothing to do with keep-alives and connections not being closed.  The problem is at the other end ... connections that are never properly established in the first place clogging up memory, and each one tying up a thread / thread stack:

- Try reducing the connect timeout.
- Try running these requests using an `Executor` with a bounded thread pool.

Note what it says in the `AsyncTask` javadoc:

> *"AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask."*

Comment: I did:  
- move 'http.keepalive' and 'http.maxConnections' command at the beginning of the method  
- move 'conn' declaration inside the method  
- remove 'is.close()' command  
However, the problem still remains.  
  
Do you have any idea what could be wrong? Interesting is that the problem appears only when connection to server fails (timeout).

Comment: 1) Have you got clear evidence that the problem IS leaking HTTP connections?  Or is that just a theory?  2) Have you considered the issue in bullet #2?  Is your app using multiple threads for downloading?

Comment: Ad 1) Yes. MAT for Eclipse shows:  568 instances of "libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 1.448.712 (15,07%) bytes.  
Ad 2) Yes, I moved 'conn' variable **inside** the method but the problem remains.  
Ad 3) App uses AsyncTask for this purpose, so it **is** possible that there are multiple instances of this method being executed concurrently.